Matlab's genetic algorithm ignores obstacle when pathfinding in 2D space
I'm playing with Matlab's Global Optimization Toolbox and learning about genetic algorithms. My goal is to implement an algorithm that can navigate in 2D space, searching for the shortest path from a start point to an end point while avoiding simple, static obstacles along the way.
start_point = [65, 275];
end_point = [510, 210];
num_points = 4; % How many intermediate points between start and finish
% Dimensions of the 2D space
x_min = 0; 
x_max = 600;
y_min = 0;
y_max = 600;

% The obstacle is a polygon with given vertices
obstacle_x = [30, 100, 170, 220, 195, 130, 130, 100];
obstacle_y = [215, 170, 210, 260, 330, 340, 280, 230];

% Constraints
lb = repmat([x_min, y_min], num_points, 1);
ub = repmat([x_max, y_max], num_points, 1);

options = optimoptions('ga', ...
    'PopulationSize', 100, ... 
    'MaxGenerations', 150, ... 
    'Display', 'final', ...
    'UseParallel', true);

objective_function = @(points) objective(points, start_point, end_point, obstacle_x, obstacle_y);

[best_points, fval] = ga(objective_function, num_points * 2, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, @constraints, options);

% Draw everything on a graph
full_path = [start_point; reshape(best_points, num_points, 2); end_point];

figure;
plot(full_path(:, 1), full_path(:, 2), '-o', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
title('Shortest path around obstacle');
grid on;
hold on;
scatter(start_point(1), start_point(2), 100, 'g', 'filled');
scatter(end_point(1), end_point(2), 100, 'r', 'filled');

fill(obstacle_x, obstacle_y, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7], 'EdgeColor', 'k');

legend('Path', 'Start', 'End', 'Obstacle', 'Location', 'Best');
hold off;

% Objective function
function d = objective(points, start_point, end_point, obstacle_x, obstacle_y)
    full_points = [start_point; reshape(points, [], 2); end_point];
    
    d = sum(sqrt(sum(diff(full_points).^2, 2)));
    
    % Penalize touching obstacle
    [in_poly, ~] = inpolygon(full_points(:, 1), full_points(:, 2), obstacle_x, obstacle_y);
    
    if any(in_poly)
        d = d + 10000 * sum(in_poly);
    end
end

function [c, ceq] = constraints(points)
    c = [];
    ceq = [];
end

My problem is that when I run this code the algorithm seems to ignore my obstacle, going in a straight line towards the end point.
The issue remains consistent when I run the algorithm with different population sizes and max generation constraints

I unfortunately do not have the optimization toolbox to test your code, but I think I know what happens: You test for your points not to intersect with your obstacles, but you don't test for the segments joining your points together for intersection with your obstacles.

I think polyxpoly will help you know if there is an intersection between your segments and your obstacles
